# mySQL - Obtain only users from a table with max points

Tags: mysql

I need to obtain **n** users from a table with the max points.

**Table**

```
id   name   points
1     pep     4
2     roky    5
3     jhon    2
4     sant    5
```

The query result will be **'roky'** and **'sant'**.

I have used a subquery like this

```
SELECT name FROM table
WHERE points = (SELECT MAX(points) FROM table)
```

Is it possible to do with only one query (no sub-queries and no joins)?

Comment: Why no subqueries? Why no joins? Is this a theoretical question?

Comment: I want to know if it's possible and by the other hand test if is most efficient too :)

Comment: If you have an index on `(points)`, it is as efficient as possible. And no, it's not possible without subqueries or joins.

Comment: Thanks ypercube for quickly answer, question solved

Comment: If you really have to find out if it is efficient enough for you, make a test table, insert a few thousands or millions (or billions) rows and test with various queries (that produce the same result) and various indexes and engines.

Answer (score 1):

You're pretty much on the right track. It needs a subquery of some sort.

See [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html) to see how the MySQL manual does it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm really not sure if this could work. Select the max points from the table, then join itself using the points number. It could potentially display the needed names without a subquery. But of course, the subquery is the better (and faster) answer.

```
SELECT max(t1.points) as maxpoints, t2.name FROM table t1
INNER JOIN table t2 on t2.points = maxpoints
```

Edit: Wait, what? No joins? Since when was this part of the task? Okay, my solution was outdated while writing it. Oh well.

Comment: Thanks anyway :) we think this is not possible if we will not using joins o subquerys

Answer (score -1):

Sort the result by row and get the first one.

```
SELEC name FROM table
ORDER BY points DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: that's not the answer to the question. Result should be 2 rows in this example, but can be any integer